# Complete request with latest item in a flow

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http, reactive-streams

I'd like to complete a `GET` request with the latest available item in a flow. This flow in particular aggregates events produced by an actor and already individually consumed by a WebSocket.

Let's say that the event can be represented as follows:

```
final case class Event(id: String, value: Double)
```

The first thing I do is creating a `SourceQueue` where the actor will push the events and a hub so that different clients can receive these events independently:

```
val (queue, hub) =
  Source.queue[Event](256, OverflowStrategy.dropHead).
    toMat(BroadcastHub.sink(bufferSize = 256))(Keep.both).run()
```

I'm then able to create an actor which can push events to `queue` and pass `hub` to a service which serves the events via a WebSocket:

```
extractUpgradeToWebSocket { upgrade =>
  complete(upgrade.handleMessagesWithSinkSource(
    inSink = Sink.ignore,
    outSource =
      hub.map(in => TextMessage(fmt.write(in).toString()))
  ))
}
```

This works fine, also with multiple consumers at the same time.

What I would like to do next is have a service which consumes the events from `hub` and produces a list of the latest event per id, serving it via a `GET` endpoint.

I tried several approaches to solve this one. The two approaches I attempted were:

- run a flow that updates a private variable
- complete with a sink that returns the `last` element

#### Run a flow that updates a private variable

This is the last approach I tried, actually. The weird (or is it?) think I noticed is that actually nothing gets logged (shouldn't thing that go through the `log` combinator be logged?).

The result using this approach is that `latest` is alway `null` and the response is thus always empty.

```
final class Service(hub: Source[Event, NotUsed])(implicit s: ActorSystem, m: ActorMaterializer, t: Timeout) extends Directives with JsonSupport {

  implicit private val executor = system.dispatcher

  @volatile private[this] var latest: List[Event] = _

  hub.
    log("hub", identity).
    groupBy(Int.MaxValue, { case Event(id, _) => id }).
    map { case event @ Event(id, _) => Map(id -> event) }.
    reduce(_ ++ _).
    mergeSubstreams.
    map(_.values.toList).
    toMat(Sink.foreach(latest = _))(Keep.none).run()

  val definition = get { complete(Option(latest)) }

}
```

I also tried a similar approach that uses a "box" actor and pipes the aggregates to it, but the effect is the same.

#### Complete with a sink that returns the `last` element

This is the first approach I tried to take. The effect is that the response hangs until a timeout is reached and Akka HTTP returns a 500 to the browser.

```
final class Service(hub: Source[Event, NotUsed])(implicit s: ActorSystem, m: ActorMaterializer, t: Timeout) extends Directives with JsonSupport {

  implicit private val executor = system.dispatcher
  private[this] val currentLocations =
    hub.
      groupBy(Int.MaxValue, { case Event(id, _) => id }).
      map { case event @ Event(id, _) => Map(id -> event) }.
      reduce(_ ++ _).
      mergeSubstreams.
      map(_.values.toList).
      runWith(Sink.reduce((_, next) => next))

  val definition = get { complete(currentLocations) }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`ActorRef` As A Sink**

You can create an `Actor` that keeps a running `Map` of `id` to `Event`:

```
import scala.collection.immutable

object QueryMap

class MapKeeperActor() extends Actor {

  var internalMap = immutable.Map.empty[String, Event]

  override def receive = {
    case e : Event    => internalMap = internalMap + (e.id -> e)
    case _ : QueryMap => sender ! internalMap
  }
}
```

This ref can then be used within a `Sink` which will be attached to the `BroadcastHub`:

```
object OnCompleteMessage

val system : ActorSystem = ???

val mapKeeperRef = system.actorOf(Props[MapKeeperActor])

val mapKeeperSink : Sink[Event, _] = Sink.actorRef[Event](mapKeeperRef, OnCompleteMessage)
```

**Query Actor in Route**

We can now create a `Route` which will query the map keeper using Directives.  However, you will have to decide how to serialize the `Map` into a `ResponseEntity` for the `HttpResponse`:

```
val serializeMap : Map[String, Event] => ResponseEntity = ???

val route = 
  get {
    onComplete( (mapKeeperRef ? QueryMap).mapTo[Map[String, Event]]) {
      case Success(map) => complete(HttpResponse(entity=serializeMap(map))
      case Failure(ex)  => complete((InternalServerError, s"An error occurred: ${ex.getMessage}"))
    }
  }
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay, it's for a pet project and I seldom have the time to make progress on it. I'll try out your approach ASAP. :)